# How to allow ActiveX install prompt to display if installed ActiveX has older version

Tags: c#, asp.net, activex

I have updated code for ActiveX functionality which already installed on client(in their Windows system folder). Now all I want to display install Active prompt window on Internet explorer which usually displays when there is no ActiveX installed for the same.

My ActiveX installs using a CAB file which contains .inf file. In both my ActiveX source code (C#) and in .inf file, I changed new Guid/ clsid as well in ASP.NET IE application where the particular control is being used. I changed the FileVersion also in .inf file but even then IE automatically detects that ActiveX is installed (which installed when CAB file had different FileVersion in .inf file) and does not prompt me to install.

If I delete my activeX DLL from windows system folder then IE prompts to install which is as usual but my need is to update ActiveX DLL if it finds newer version.
Please let me know if I am not using correct way to make new version like I am using FileVersion of inf file or anyother place where I need to define new version so that I will get my desired functionality.

Best Regards,

Anurag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get automatic upgrade, you need to update the following two things:

1. In the inf file, update the value of FileVersion

> ```
> [DynamicWebTwainCtrl.dll]
> file-win32-x86=thiscab
> clsid={E7DA7F8D-27AB-4EE9-8FC0-3FEC9ECFE758}
> FileVersion=7,0,0,0
> RegisterServer=yes
> RedirectToHKCU=yes
> ```

1. Update the version number in your source code.

> ```
> <object classid="clsid:FFC6F181-A5CF-4ec4-A441-093D7134FBF2" id="DynamicWebTwain1" width="143" height="156"
> CodeBase = "DynamicWebTWAIN.cab#version=7,0">
>   <param name="_cx" value="847" />
>   <param name="_cy" value="847" />
>   <param name="JpgQuality" value="80" />
>   <param name="Manufacturer" value="Dynamsoft Corporation" />
>   <param name="ProductFamily" value="Dynamic Web TWAIN" />
>   <param name="ProductName" value="Dynamic Web TWAIN" />
>   <param name="VersionInfo" value="Dynamic Web TWAIN 7.0" />
> </object>
> ```

Comment: Thanks Windy, this helped. Though, I am not able to replace new DLL, perhaps because existing one is in use but able to get install prompt.